# Gulp image optimizer(gulp-imagemin) not fully optimize

Tags: gulp, gulp-imagemin

I am using gulp to compile my work, Recently I am using gulp-imagemin plugin to optimize the images, and its working but still not fully optimize.On Google PageSpeed Insights showing the images are not fully optimize.How to fully optimize my images? Please help.
This is the function I am using on my gulpfile.js, And it reducing about 2-5% images size.But not fully optimize.

```
gulp.task('imgs', function () {
    gulp
        .src(paths.assets.images)
        .pipe(imagemin({
            progressive: true,
            interlaced: true,
            pngquant: true
        }))
        .pipe(flatten())
        .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.build + "/img"));
});
```

Here is the screenshot where Google PageSpeed Insights showing images are not optimize.
[image: screenshot]

Comment: What does the "Optimize the following images" link recommend? I know that PageSpeed often recommends using WebP in which case `gulp-imagemin` won't help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This one working much better..

```
gulp.task('imgs', function () {
    gulp
        .src(paths.assets.images)
        .pipe(cache(imagemin({ optimizationLevel: 3, progressive: true, interlaced: true })))
        .pipe(flatten())
        .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.build + "/images"));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I've just faced with the same trouble and I decided to move from the default **imagemin-jpegtran** to a **imageminMozjpeg** plugin.

First you need to install imagemin-mozjpeg:

`npm install --save imagemin-mozjpeg`

Then add this row into your gulpfile.js:

`var imageminMozjpeg = require('imagemin-mozjpeg');`

And slightly change the code where you piped the imagemin tool

```
.pipe(imagemin(
    [imageminMozjpeg()],
    {verbose: true}         // Enabling this will log info on every image passed to gulp-imagemin
))
```

It also removes images metadata. The result is amazing:
[gulp-imagemin working process log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VBLMM.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Use gulp-image with imagemin jpegRecompress plugin. It is giving much better result. File size reducing by more than 70%. You just have to take care of error handling because some times command fails.